# How to implement JavaScript Design Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I am looking for a JS solution / design pattern that allows to call the function C.Test.init() multiple times with binding the window load event in the init() function. Unfortunately I cannot get this to work. Can anyone help me with this?

```
    var C = {};

    C.Test = (function(C)
    {
        var me = {};

        me.init = function(config)
        {
            me._config = config;
            $(window).bind('load.' + config.name, me, me.sayHello);
        }

        me.sayHello = function(e)
        {
            // this doesn't work:
            document.write('HELLO ' + me._config.name + '<br>');

            // this doesn't work either:
            document.write('SALVE ' + e.data._config.name + '<br>');
        }

        return {
            init : me.init
        }

    })(C);

    C.Test.init({
        name: 'John'
    });

    C.Test.init({
        name: 'Kate'
    });
```

Here's the JS Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ss8L/

Comment: Why have you tagged this as jQuery? Do you want a jQuery solution?

Comment: because i am using jquery to bind the load event. a solution in jquery would also suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like a closure issue to me

http://jsfiddle.net/4Ss8L/2/

check this out.

Comment: and if u want the data to be added in event.data then u'll have to do something like this

`$(window).bind('load.' + config.name, function (c) {return function (e) {e.data = c;me.sayHello.call(this, e);}}(config));`

reason being u are using a singleton or rather an object to access data and by the time the window's load is fired the _config is changed and the old reference of data is overridden.
here's the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/4Ss8L/3/

Comment: great. thank you @Sushil! one more question though: is the "return" really needed? it also works without it.

Comment: @santacruz no, in your scenario its not needed but in some cases it is, so it's kind of in case to case basis. But if you remove the return statement you'll not get the event object. check our the fiddle link i gave u in my previous comment.